# devise change redirect after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried the code on Devise's github.  In my application controller, i have:

```
after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/password" ) 
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    puts 'stores location'
  end
end

def after_update_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_url] || dashboard_path
  puts 'after update'
end
```

When I check my server, the puts statement from the store_location method appears, but the puts statement from after_update_path_for does not.  How do I get the after_update_redirect to work?

Here is what devise says to do, but it isn't working:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?  I can't get it figured out.

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation:

> **(Object) after_update_path_for(resource)** (protected)
>   The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.

So creating your ow RegistrationsController is correct. Here is a simpler solution though:

`after_update_path_for` calls `signed_in_root_path(resource)` which looks a home `#{scope}_root_path`. Scope here is often `user` (but if not you probably know what it is). In the case of 'user', implementing `user_root_path` in your application controller, returning your `dashboard_url`, should work.

```
def user_root_path
  dashboard_url
end
```

Although it seemed a bit hackish to me at first, I believe it is quite 'ok';  the root path for the user-scope is could indeed be the dashboard page.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how i solved the problem:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    protected

    def after_update_path_for(resource)
        puts 'this is happening yoyo mama'
        flash[:notice] = "Account succesfully updated"
        edit_user_registration_path
    end
end
```

routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
```

The only problem is that this will only do the redirect if changing the password is successful.  If not, the redirect does not happen.  Does anyone know how to make it so the redirect will also happen if there are errors?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile), override the default and add the route. There's no need to set the flash message unless of course you want to change that as well.

```
# Example subclass/override (registrations_controller.rb)
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end
end

# Example routing config (in routes.rb):
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
```

Comment: `user_path(resource)` didn't work for me, neither `current_user`. So, I simply used: `"/users/#{resource.id}"`

Answer (score 0):

`respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)` is the code which set the redirection path after update. To change the default redirect, override following method in your application controller by adding the following code

```
def after_update_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  dashboard_url
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  I don't think the method is being called.  I put a puts statement inside and it never made it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the route in the ApplicationController also did not work for me, but adding it to the Users::RegistrationsController worked.
For example,

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def after_update_path_for(resource)
    current_user
end
```

on a related note, the after_sign_in_path can be added to the SessionsController

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  current_user
end
```

my routes look like this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  confirmations: "users/confirmations",
  passwords: "users/passwords",
  registrations: "users/registrations",
  sessions: "users/sessions",
  unlocks: "users/unlocks",
}
```